# Transparent color over image without wrapper

Tags: css

I am trying to add a semi-transparent color layer to the top of an image for the background of a div. I have tried the following:

```
background: url('myImage.jpg'), rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

Also

```
background-image:url('myImage.jpg');
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

But in both cases just the image shows up. I know I could wrap this div in another div with the color, but is there any way I could do it all in a single div?

Comment: Your first version seems to be working fine in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/w8H8d/.  However, browser support is still a little spotty: http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: @fordareh - Actually, support is pretty good, even IE9 supports it (which, given the bizzarre choices that team made with regard to what to support, is impressive). http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

Comment: yeah - I agree, it's just that I wasn't having any trouble seeing it with your code in the fiddle.  So, I figured maybe you were in IE8.  Looks like you got it taken care of, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `:after` selector. It could solve your issue.

```
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Example is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ecYrS/2/

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't support what you're trying to do natively - you'd need to lay an RGBa layer over the image. You basically want an translucent layer over the background image, but CSS is going to set precedence on the background image, essentially overriding any background color.

One thought is you could try an alpha-transparent PNG, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: Idea with alpha-transperent PNG sound really nice! I kept that in my mind for future, thanks.

Comment: An extra request just for a transparent layer? Pretty overkill and bad style for today

Answer (score -1):

@Flynn face the same issue as you mentioned. I figured out a pretty handy solution.

There is a way though!

Instead of using a transparent flood color using rgba() or hsla(), we can use a gradient. Gradients are technically background-images and thus not subject to the rule where they can't come first (be top) in the stacking order.

```html
/* Working method */
.tinted-image {
  background: 
    /* top, transparent red, faked with gradient */ 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),
    /* bottom, image */
    url(image.jpg);
}
```

for more information, please explore following link:

[image with background color](https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/)